# How to upload files directly from Django admin to Amazon S3? Mitigating Heroku Application Error (timeout)

Tags: django, heroku, amazon-s3, django-admin

I have an app on Heroku (the free plan) and regularly get *Application Error* on media files uploads from Django admin. I use S3 for serving static&media. 
What is the best way to upload files to S3 directly via django admin? Or maybe there is some other way to mitigate this problem (withot adding dynos)?

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

1. [s3 direct](https://github.com/bradleyg/django-s3direct).:
   With s3 direct the file would be uploaded directly to s3.
2. Increase Server Timeout
   You can increase your server timeout --- guessing you are using [Gunicorn](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/python-gunicorn#worker-timeouts) .
   Note that this could have repercussions, unfortunately I don't fully know what kind of [repercussions](http://docs.gunicorn.org/en/latest/settings.html#timeout)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [django-storages](http://django-storages.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) for this

Comment: How does that help? The problem occurs if file upload through admin takes more than 30 seconds. Then we run into the heroku timeout.

Answer (score 0):

@acquayefrank's suggestion worked for me. I have a Django project and I was having trouble uploading about 120 MB+ files through the Django Admin.

I changed my Procfile to say this (replace `yourname` with the dotted path to your .wsgi):

```
web: gunicorn --timeout 120 yourname.wsgi --log-file -
```

I can't say for certain that this will solve everyone's same issue but might be worth a try.

Answer (score 0):

[This](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/s3-upload-python) article outlines how you can upload directly to S3 with the assistance of Javascript. You could then potentially use [custom Javascript in the Django admin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910450/how-to-load-a-custom-js-file-in-django-admin-home) to achieve the same outcome. Hope it helps.