# How to load a custom JS file in Django admin home?

Tags: javascript, python, django, django-admin, django-staticfiles

I have a heavily customized Django admin where it's very simple to load a custom JS file for each of my ModelAdmins:

```py
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    class Media:
        js = ('js/admin/mymodel.js',)
```

But how do I do this for the admin "homepage," where all my admin models are listed?

**Update #1**: amending my question, since the solutions below aren't that useful if I cannot efficiently include Django's jQuery. So, how do I include Django's jQuery in the JS file?  If I wrap my code with (as I do in my other ModelAdmin JS files):

```js
(function ($) {
    // my code here...
})(django.jQuery);
```

I get the following error:

> ReferenceError: django is not defined.

Thanks.

**Update #2**: I was able to include Django's jQuery successfully by following this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10584539/585783

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can override `templates/admin/index.html` and add the JavaScript in the block `extrahead`:

```
{% extends "admin/index.html" %}

{% block extrahead %}
    {{ block.super }}
    # add a <script> tag here with your JavaScript
{% endblock %}
```

Comment: This works and seems clean, thanks...  However, how do I include jQuery in the JS file?  If I wrap my code with `(function ($) { ... })(django.jQuery);` the same as in my other ModelAdmin JS files, I get a "ReferenceError: django is not defined"

Comment: jQuery is pre-bundled in the Django admin - you don't need to add it in manually.

Comment: The above solution will overwrite all code contained in the extrahead block, which might be the reason for the "ReferenceError: django is not defined" error. If you add a `{{ block.super }}` inside the `{% block extrahead %} ... {% endblock %}` existing code is preserved.

Comment: @tobltobs I updated the answer. Does it look correct now?

Comment: It doesn't work. Adding template to `templates/admin/index.html` doesn't change anything.

Comment: @EugZol having the same problem, did this change?

Comment: @MikeSchem That was a long time ago and I don't remember what I did next. Currently I see `./template/admin/<app_name>/base_site.html`. First line of that file is `{% extends "admin/base_site.html" %}`. `<app_name>` is a name of subfolder in the project, where I put all admin models. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 3):

You can load custom `js` files only on `Home` admin page. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30313314/how-to-include-javascript-in-django-templates/76983969#76983969) explains how to load CSS and JavaScript files in Django.

For example, set `BASE_DIR / 'templates'` to [DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#dirs) in [TEMPLATES](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#templates) and set `BASE_DIR / 'static/'` to [STATICFILES_DIRS](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/settings/#staticfiles-dirs) in `settings.py` as shown below so that Django can recognize `templates` and `static` folders just under `django-project`. *[My answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1926049/django-templatedoesnotexist#72359515) explains how to set Django Templates and I recommand to set [whitenoise](https://github.com/evansd/whitenoise) following [my answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7013735/turn-off-caching-of-static-files-in-django-development-server/76971577#76971577) to disable your browser to cache the static files of Django: in `settings.py` as shown below:

```py
# "core/settings.py"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [
            BASE_DIR / 'templates' # Here
        ],
        ...
    },
]

...

STATIC_URL = 'static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    BASE_DIR / 'static/' # Here
]
```

Then, create `custom.js` in `static/admin/js/` and copy [index.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html) from `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/index.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |-app2
 |-static
 |  └-admin
 |     └-js
 |        └-custom.js # Here
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-index.html # Here
```

Then, set `alert("Hello World");` to `custom.js` as shown below:

```js
# "static/admin/js/custom.js"

alert("Hello World");
```

Then, set `custom.js` after `{% block sidebar %}` in `index.html` as shown below:

```
# "templates/admin/index.html"

# ...
{% block sidebar %}
{# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ #}
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/custom.js' %}" defer></script>
{# ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ #}
<div id="content-related">
# ...
```

Now, `Hello World` is shown only on `Home` admin page as shown below:

[image]

In addition, you can load `custom.js` on all admin pages.

So, copy [base.html](https://github.com/django/django/blob/main/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/base.html) from `django/contrib/admin/static/admin/base.html` in your virtual environment to `templates/admin/` as shown below:

```
django-project
 |-core
 |  └-settings.py
 |-app1
 |-app2
 |-static
 |  └-admin
 |     └-js
 |        └-custom.js
 └-templates
    └-admin
       └-base.html # Here
```

Then, set `custom.js` after `<link ... "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">` in `base.html` as shown below, then `Hello World` is shown on all admin pages:

```
# "templates/admin/base.html"

# ...
<title>{% block title %}{% endblock %}</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{% block stylesheet %}{% static "admin/css/base.css" %}{% endblock %}">
{# ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ Here ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ ↓ #}
<script src="{% static 'admin/js/custom.js' %}" defer></script>
{# ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ Here ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ ↑ #}
{% block dark-mode-vars %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static "admin/css/dark_mode.css" %}">
# ...
```

Be careful, [django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js/](https://github.com/django/django/tree/main/django/contrib/admin/static/admin/js) has the `js` files for Django Admin so you should not use the same file names in it to add custom `js` files to Django Admin as long as you need to overwrite them.

And, running the code below can gether all static files in Django Project into `static` folder without deleting custom and overwritten `js` files.

```
python manage.py collectstatic
```