# Graciously handle crash while saving model via Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

Sometimes it is **not possible** to know **beforehand** and graciously reject model save inside a **validator** which shows nice error message in Django Admin.

If a specific crash happens during the **save** operation (e.g. data integrity error) and we still want to catch it and show a nice error (similar to validation errors), there's no obvious way to do this that I could find.

I tried overriding the `save_model` method on Django Admin, but this is a horrible thing to do according to the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-methods):

> When overriding ModelAdmin.save_model() and ModelAdmin.delete_model(), your code must save/delete the object. They **aren’t meant for veto purposes**, rather they allow you to perform extra operations.

What's the correct way to catch specific exceptions and display nice error message then?

UPDATE:

**Example**: integrity error when using optimistic locking.

More **concrete example**: `ConcurrentTransition` error raised by `django_fsm` when the object's state has been changed in DB since the object was loaded by Admin (this could be considered a light version of optimistic locking).

Comment: I may be wrong, but the way you are using django-admin is an extension beyond its original purpose.  My reason for stating that is that you need staff status to access.  So they aren't meant to support complex workflows and validations.  With that being said its a great way to rapidly prototype and extend.  So in terms of error catching, IMO, do that with javascript.  Its easy to inject custom js in admin - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910450/how-to-load-a-custom-js-file-in-django-admin-home.  Or you could do a custom save_model.  Its not built for that but you could construct it.

Comment: Can you give an example of an issue that couldn't be caught at validation time but which causes integrity errors?

Comment: @sahutchi thanks for your opinion, I know Django Admin isn't the answer for everything, yet I feel this isn't such so dramatic that it couldn't be handled by Admin.

Comment: @DanielRoseman I updated the comment to provide a concrete example, but really this doesn't matter that much - I've come across this issue many times in the past, with other runtime exceptions. It is not so hard to imagine, this is really a general issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an elegant way to solve this without hacking the `save_model` method which is not intended for veto purposes.

Instead, it's enough to just override `change_view` and/or `add_view` and generate an error message if they crash.

Example:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def change_view(self, request, object_id, form_url='', extra_context=None):
    try:
        return super(MyAdmin, self).change_view(request, object_id, form_url, extra_context)
    except MyException as err:
        messages.error(request, err)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

**edit**: This more generic handler catches errors from Admin's AddForm as well:

```
from django.contrib import messages
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect

def changeform_view(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    try:
        return super().changeform_view(request, *args, **kwargs)
    except IOError as err:
        self.message_user(request, str(err), level=messages.ERROR)
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path)
```

Comment: Can you elaborate a little more? What's  `MyAdmin` here and where to define this function? and where to call this function?

Comment: `MyAdmin` is an example of a custom `ModelAdmin`-derived class that is supposed to handle the error in question. You'd define/override this `changeform_view` (or `change_view`) method on this class, which is itself usually defined in your app/`admin.py` module.