# Adding keyboard shortcust functionality to Django Admin

Tags: python, django, django-admin, keyboard-shortcuts

What is the easiest way to add ***keyboard shortcuts*** to ***Django admin panel*** without overriding admin templates? 
Like **new object**, s**ave object**, **delete object** and etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if this is possible. 
You could just override the admin template and extend it, so you could load a custom JS file to do your shortcuts.

Check out this answer, i believe it may help you: 
[How to load a custom JS file in Django admin home?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910450/how-to-load-a-custom-js-file-in-django-admin-home/19910749#19910749)