# add a javascript file to django admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I seem to have hit a wall trying to do a very simple thing: 
Integrate a js file into a Django model admin. I am adding a Media class like so:

```
class Media:
    css = { "all": ("job_run.css",) }
    js = ("job_run.js",)
```

I put both files in the same folder, but only the css gets actually "published" by the server (I can only see the job_run.css included in the chrome devtools).
This is probably a file (job_run.js) location problem, but I don't seem to be able to find the right folder to put it under my projects.
A second possible error is that I should specify somewhere the Media folder for inclusion. Could not find a good reference how to do so.

Any clues?

Comment: maybe this can break the wall : https://stackoverflow.com/a/19910749/5644965

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create a folder named "static" inside your app and inside the 'static' folder create one more folder with your app_name. inside that folder create two folders 'css' and 'js'. Put your css and js file accordingly.

Then

```
class Media:
    css = { "all": ("app_name/css/job_run.css",) }
    js = ("app_name/js/job_run.js",)
```

Comment: Works like a charm! Thanks! Amazingly enough I managed to do it in every other way ;-)

Comment: Please note you need to add this in admin.py where you register your model. 
```Class ModelObject(admin.ModelAdmin): \n
    ... \n
    class Media: \n
        ...```