# How to know if a user arrived at the login page after clicking a logout? Django

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I am using the django's built-in auth module for user authentication.

**urls.py**

```
url(r'^accounts/logout/', auth_views.logout, kwargs={'next_page': reverse_lazy('login')}),
url(r'^accounts/login/', auth_views.login, name='login', kwargs={'redirect_authenticated_user': True,"authentication_form":CustomAuthForm}),
```

The user is redirected to `login` page immediately after  logout. But I need to display a "*signed out!*" message to the user in the login page.

How would I know whether a user clicked the ***logout*** link to arrive at ***login*** page or he/she directly visited ***login***(in this case I won't show any message).

Comment: Why don't you use javascript to check if the button has clicked or not and then display your message? Here's an answer of including javascript in django admin: [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19910450/how-to-load-a-custom-js-file-in-django-admin-home)

Comment: @Shiri How would javascript help if a button is clicked from a page other than the current one leading to a redirect to the current page? Please go through the question again.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the [Django messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) is something you could use here - in the `logout.post`, you'd need to add a message `messages.success(request, 'Successfully logged out.')` that would be rendered by your login template.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [The messages framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/messages/) from Django, like this:

```
from django.contrib.messages import get_messages

def logout(request, ...):

    # Logout the user
    # Add a logout message
    messages.add_message(request, messages.SUCCESS, "signed out!")

    return HttpResponseRedirect(...)

def login(request, ...):
    storage = get_messages(request)
    for message in storage:
        msg = message
        break
    return render(request, 'your_app/login.html', {'message': msg})
```

Then in your `login.html` template, check if message is not None and display it.
Inject this where you want the message to be displayed

```
{% if message %}
<div>
   {{ message }}
</div>
{% endif %}
```